# What does the z-score in power calculations mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

I have been trying to understand the meaning of power in hypothesis testing, and thought that I understood it, initially.  To put it simply, it is the probability that the test will correctly see a difference where it exists.  In other words, (and more technically), $$P(reject\, H_0 / H_1 \, is \, true)$$Then, most text books then suggest that this is just $1-\beta$ where $\beta$ is the probability of type II errors, but only two made any attempt to show how $\beta$ was calculated.  The two that did had different approaches.

The first showed the following graph

[image: two normal distribution graphs overlaid on top of each other, the first with a mean at 80 and the second at 88, both with a standard deviation of 5. Shaded areas show the rejection regions of greater than 90 and less than 70. A secondary x-axis is shown showing the relative positions of the z-scores for the first graph, including 0, and plus and minus 1.96.]

So $\beta$ can be calculated easily by calculating shifting the z-axis to center around the distribution of the treatment, and adding the probabilities of the "shaded" areas on the left and right (note, the one on the left in the image is incorrect, it should be shaded from the second graph, but it gets the concept across).

The second book does a similar explanation (without the neat graph) but then suggests that the transformation to the z-score is 
$$z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} $$
**Why is the transformation equation different to the typical z-score transformation equation below, i.e. where does the $/\sqrt{n}$ term come from?** 
$$z=\frac{\bar{x}-\mu}{\sigma} $$ 
Two elements to this question -

1. why do they use a non-standard transformation equation for X to z (is it standard to use this new definition?
2. why don't they just use t-values instead of z-scores?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. typical z-score transformation equation is for individual X, (in your equation, $\bar x$ should be $x$). For individual $X$, its variance is $\sigma^2$. When you perform the test of the mean, the sample mean $\bar x$ is used, and its variance is $\sigma^2/n$. So the different denominators(square root of variance) are used.
2. Because $\bar x/\text{se}(\bar x)$ follows t distribution.

Comment: Oh of course, the distribution shown in the image is a distribution of sample means, thus $\sigma_M$.  Thanks.  Sorry for wasting your time on what turns out to be a miss-reading of the original graph.